# При выводе массива в консоли я вижу не то, что нужно? Java

Tags: java, массивы

Новичек, изучаю Java.
Есть несколько классов Tracker(используется как хранилище заявок),Item(сама заявка), StartUI(Точка входа в программу),

```
//Класс Tracker
public Item[] findAll(){
    return Arrays.copyOf(this.items, this.position);
}

//Класс StartUI
private void showItems(){
    System.out.println("----- Вывод всех заявок ----");
    for (Item arr : this.tracker.findAll())
        System.out.println(arr);
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(this.tracker.findAll()));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(this.tracker.findAll()));
    ArrayList<Item> arrayList = new ArrayList<Item>(Arrays.asList(this.tracker.findAll()));
    System.out.println(arrayList);
}
```

Пробовал Arrays.asList, Arrays.toString, ArrayList, выводится все равно 
tracker.Item@12a3a380
Не пойму в чем дело

Comment: У вас должен быть переопределён метод `toString()` в классах. Вам нужно пользоваться функцией `Arrays.toString()`

Comment: нужно переопределить метод toString() для тех объектов, которые нужно выводить